# Finding probabilities from a piecewise cdf function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX1Tx.png)

I want to find $P(1\leq x<2)$. The answer key says that it is $1/4$. I am not sure how that is the answer, as I am thinking that it should be $P(x<2) - P(x\leq1)$ which is $3/4 - 2/3 = 1/12$. I'm assuming that the answer is found with $43/4 - 1/2 = 1/4$, but where does that $1/2$ come from? Is it $P(x<1)$?-

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac12$ is indeed  $P(X<1)= \lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}F(x) $, as in :

$$\begin{align} & P(1\le X<2) \\= &  P(X <2) - P(X \lt 1)  \\=  & \lim\limits_{x\to 2^-}F(x) -\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}F(x) \\= & \left(\frac2{12}+\frac7{12}\right)- \frac12
\\= & \frac9{12}- \frac12 \\= & \frac1{4}\end{align}$$

In both cases, you are taking $\lim F(x)$ from below.

Answer (score 0):

$F(x)=P(X \leq x)$. For $P(X<x)$ you have to take the left-hand limit of $F$ at $x$: $P(X<x)=\lim_{y\to x, y<x} F(y)$.  So $P(X<2)=\frac 9 {12}$ and $P(X<1)=\frac 1  2$. So the answer is $\frac 9 {12}-\frac  1 2=\frac  1 4$.

Comment: But if it is P(X≤x), then shouldn't you take the right hand limit, which for P(x≤1) is 2/3?

Comment: @matthh5 $P(X\leq 2)=F(x)$ but $P(X<2)=\lim_{n\to \infty} F(x-\frac  1n)$.